# Texture sampler in HLSL does not interpolate

Tags: directx, textures, directx-11, hlsl, pixel-shader

I am currently working on a multi-textured terrain and I have problems with the [Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn393894(v=vs.85).aspx) function of [Texture2DArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471526(v=vs.85).aspx).

In my example, I use a [Texture2DArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471526(v=vs.85).aspx) to store a set of different terrain texture, e.g. grass, sand, asphalt, etc. Each of my vertices stores a texture coordinate (UV coordinate) and an index of the texture I want to use. So, if my index is 0, I use the first texture. If the index is 1, I use the second texture, and so on. This works fine, as long as my index is a natural number (0, 1, ..). However, it fails, if the index is a real number (like 1.5f).

In order to look for the problem, I reduced my entire pixel shader to this:

```
Texture2DArray DiffuseTextures : register(t0);
Texture2DArray NormalTextures : register(t1);
Texture2DArray EmissiveTextures : register(t2);
Texture2DArray SpecularTextures : register(t3);
SamplerState Sampler : register(s0);

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 nor : NORMAL;
    float3 tan : TANGENT;
    float3 bin : BINORMAL;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float4 TextureIndices : COLOR1;
    float4 tra : COLOR2;
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 PS(PS_IN input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 texCol = DiffuseTextures.Sample(Sampler, float3(input.TextureUV, input.TextureIndices.r));

    return texCol;
}
```

The following image shows the result of a sample scene on the left side. As you can see, there is a hard border between the used textures. There is no form of interpolation.

In order to check my texture indices, I changed my pixel shader from above by returning the texture indices as a color:

```
return float4(input.TextureIndices.r, input.TextureIndices.r, input.TextureIndices.r, 1.0f);
```

The result can be seen on the right side of the image. The texture indices are correct, since they range in the interval [0, 1] and you can clearly see the interpolation at the border of the area. However, my sampled texture does not show any form of interpolation.

[image: Example]

Since my pixel shader is pretty simple, I wonder what causes this behaviour? Is there any setting in DirextX responsible for this?

I use DirectX 11, pixel shader ps_5_0 (I also tested with ps_4_0) and I use DDS textures (BC3 compression).

**Edit**

This is the sampler I am using:

```
SharpDX.Direct3D11.SamplerStateDescription samplerStateDescription = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.SamplerStateDescription()
{
    AddressU = SharpDX.Direct3D11.TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
    AddressV = SharpDX.Direct3D11.TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
    AddressW = SharpDX.Direct3D11.TextureAddressMode.Wrap,
    Filter = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Filter.MinMagMipLinear
};

SharpDX.Direct3D11.SamplerState samplerState = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.SamplerState(_device, samplerStateDescription);

_deviceContext.PixelShader.SetSampler(0, samplerState);
```

**Solution**

I made a function using the code presented by *catflier* for getting a texture color:

```
float4 GetTextureColor(Texture2DArray textureArray, float2 textureUV, float textureIndex)
{
    float tid = textureIndex;
    int id = (int)tid;
    float l = frac(tid);

    float4 texCol1 = textureArray.Sample(Sampler, float3(textureUV, id));
    float4 texCol2 = textureArray.Sample(Sampler, float3(textureUV, id + 1));

    return lerp(texCol1, texCol2, l);
}
```

This way, I can get the desired texture color for all texture types (diffuse, specular, emissive, ...) with a simple function call:

```
float4 texCol = GetTextureColor(DiffuseTextures, input.TextureUV, input.TextureIndices.r);
float4 bumpMap = GetTextureColor(NormalTextures, input.TextureUV, input.TextureIndices.g);
float4 emiCol = GetTextureColor(EmissiveTextures, input.TextureUV, input.TextureIndices.b);
float4 speCol = GetTextureColor(SpecularTextures, input.TextureUV, input.TextureIndices.a);
```

The result is as smooth as I wanted it to be: :-)

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture arrays do not sample across slices, so technically, this is expected result.

If you want to interpolate between slices (eg: 1.5f gives you "half" of second texture and "half" of third texture), you can use a Texture3d instead, which allows this (but will cost some more as it will perform trilinear filtering)

Otherwise, you can perform your sampling that way :

```
float4 PS(PS_IN input) : SV_Target
{
    float tid = input.TextureIndices.r;
    int id = (int)tid; 
    float l = frac(tid); //lerp amount

    float4 texCol1 = DiffuseTextures.Sample(Sampler, float3(input.TextureUV,id));
    float4 texCol2 = DiffuseTextures.Sample(Sampler, float3(input.TextureUV,id+1));
return lerp(texCol1,texCol2, l);
```

}

Please note that this technique is quite more flexible, since you can also provide non adjacent slices as input (so you can lerp between slice 2 and 23 for example), and eventually use a different blend mode by changing lerp by some other function.

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thank you. I updated my post to present the solution and its result. However, I am pretty sure my code worked a few months back. But I am very happy, that everything works now.